# How To Use A Relative Path For The Eclipse Workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, portability

Whenever I move the Eclipse folder to another location, it would completely reset unless I [switch the workspace manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179328/how-to-change-the-eclipse-default-working-directory). It seems to use an absolute path, but I want a relative one to actually make it fully portable.

Any way of doing this? Where do I find the workspace path I've set?

As a side note, [referenced libraries inside projects must use relative paths to prevent a re-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980097/how-to-import-external-library-by-relative-path-in-eclipse).

Comment: relative to eclipse folder? Did you try adding `-data rel/workspace/` in `eclipse.ini` file?

Answer (score 2):

If your `workspace` is relative to your `eclipse` folder then try  adding this to the `config.ini` using relative path with [`platform schema`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/platform-scheme-uri.html) to workaround the fact that you cannot use an absolute path [according to this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/platform-scheme-uri.html).

```
-data platform:/base/workspace
```

The file is located in the root eclipse folder.

Comment: Yes, the workspace is in the same directory as the Eclipse executable. I tried your config.ini file and it would still use the "old" path when everything is moved

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on Windows  create a bat file within this command subst G: ,G is a local disque name it's just an example the only condition it to choose a disque local name that not already exist. put this bat file next to your workspace in the same level, then execute this but file ,a disque local icon with the name G or the one you had chosen will appear in your work station,then launch eclipse and chose the this path G:\workspace.the positive about this method is not only eclipse became portable but everything exist in same level of the bat file.

Answer (score 0):

On your `eclipse.ini` file, just above the line (it must be above this line)

```
-vmargs
```

Paste these lines exactly as follows (you may replace `DesiredWorkspaceName`)

```
-data
DesiredWorkspaceName
```

Do not create a directory beforehand. Eclipse will do this automatically. For things to go smoothly for the most part, you really should let Eclipse create the directory. It is imperative the `-data` is in a line all on its own.

Tested with Eclipse: product verison 4.17.0, 2020-09 R.