# Collaborating on Github with different Jar paths

Tags: java, git, github, jar

I currently have a Java repo on Github that I am collaborating with a group of developers. We have several external jar files, and each time I update my master branch the jar path changes to that of whoever made the last commit.

Is there a way to permanently add jars to java or to share jars on git to prevent this?

I have a Mac and they have PCs if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you can't include the jar files within your commits and use a relative path to them from within your project?

If you are using Eclipse, here is how you can add a jar file using a relative path [How to import external library by relative path in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980097/how-to-import-external-library-by-relative-path-in-eclipse)

Comment: I am not sure if this worked, but I tried. There seemed to be a collision after I added the variables and my coworker attempted to merge the branches.