# Allow external jar in .classpath relative to home

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, eclipse-classpath

Simply put, in Eclipse, the generated .classpath file has an external jar in the following format:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/userName/example.jar"/>
```

I want to replace /Users/username so that the path is relative to the home of whoever the user is. Like how an ant build file can have ${user.home} or how bash files can have $HOME.

Comment: Did you try Maven?

Comment: @Luke I haven't tried Maven. I actually use IntelliJ for programming but am also making the project compatible with Eclipse users who are working on the project. If possible, I would prefer if there was a simple way to replace /Users/username with a shortcut of sorts rather than add in another project management tool.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980097/how-to-import-external-library-by-relative-path-in-eclipse